# How do I fix this API/proxy connection issue

Tags: python, proxy

I am trying to connect to a website with an API connection and proxy but it is failing due to the following proxy error (bear in mind this connection has been working up to now):

> ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='datarobot-app.dataanalytics.apps.aws-euw1.avivacloud.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/version/ (Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: [https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy'](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy%27), SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1091)'))))

What I've tried so far:

- I've tried adjusting my python code to use http rather than https
- I tried to ping the website but I am getting time out requests (https://datarobot-app.dataanalytics.apps.aws-euw1.avivacloud.com/api/v2)
- I've tried creating a new API key
- Restarting the kernel, laptop etc
- I've read the recommended docs in the error description and tried the following but it has not worked:

  ```
  import urllib3
  http = urllib3.PoolManager(num_pools=75)
  ```

Nothing has worked so far.